# Label in align*-environment

Tags: cross-referencing, alignat

I want to label an `alignat*` environment and refer to it. It works with the `alignat` environment but not with `alignat*`.

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Comment: What do you want the `\ref` to return when there is no numbering in an `alignat*`?

Comment: `\label` stores the number associated with the environment so that it can be referenced with `\ref` and `alignat*` has no number.

Comment: I just want to get the page and not a number. Is that possible?

Comment: @N.Sch Try `\pageref{<label>}`.

Answer (score 3):

The "star" environments (such as `align*`, `eqn*`, and others) are made to suppress labels. To create a label, you'll need to use the standard form of the environment (`align`, `eqn`).

Comment: And what can I do if I want to get only the page?

Answer (score 1):

If you're *only* interested in referencing the page, you could use the traditional LaTeX `\label` just *before* the `alignat*`, from which you can extract the `\pageref`:

```
\label{<label>}
\begin{alignat*}{..}
  ...
\end{alignat*}
```

Perhaps using the traditional `\label` - modified by [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) to `\ltx@label` - inside should also work for you:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\labelpage}[1]{\ltx@label{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

See pages~\pageref{eq:first} and~\pageref{eq:second}.

\begin{alignat}{1}
  f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \label{eq:first}
\end{alignat}

\lipsum[1-20]

\begin{alignat*}{1}
  f(x) &= ax^2 + bx + c \labelpage{eq:second}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Since no page break will happen between the last line before the `alignat` and the display, the `\label` can safely go there.

Comment: @egreg: Good point.

Comment: Of course I assume that no `\par` intervenes between text and the `alignat*` (so `\lipsum*` should be used for the example, with no blank line).

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to use `\label` in starred display environments (`align*`, `alignat*`, `flalign*`, `gather*` and `multline*`) unless the equation we want to refer to has a `\tag`.

Conversely, `\label` can go in any line of a non-starred display environment.

So you have a couple of alternatives, if you insist in not numbering equations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

Some aligned and not numbered equations, but for one that has
a tag to which we can refer with the standard reference system
\verb|\eqref| getting \eqref{test-tag}
\begin{align*}
a &= b \\
c &= d \tag{a}\label{test-tag}
\end{align*}

Another strategy might be using the page reference, but in
this case the \verb|\label| must go between the text and
the display environment\label{test-page}
\begin{align*}
x &= y \\
u &= v
\end{align*}
and we can then refer to the page with the standard
\verb|\pageref|, getting \pageref{test-page}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using a \tag works. If you don't want the tag to print in the equation-number position, use \tag*{}. (this will also not increment the equation counter.) If you then place a label in that line called, e.g., \label{anytext}, you can refer to its line by \hyperref[anytext]{(a)}, which will print a reference to (a), or any other name you have assigned to that line, e.g., by inclusion of \text{(a)} at the start of it.

Comment: Can you please show examples for what you explain? This could also make the difference to egreg's answer more clear.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/863).